# StorageException has occurred. User is not authenticated

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

The error is risen when I try to upload to the storage. I've already implemented authentication in my app, and am having no problem with creating a user and authenticating.   StorageException has occurred.
User is not authenticated, please authenticate using Firebase Authentication and try again. Error -13020 HttpResult: 401
2022-04-28 17:26:45.646 30490-30886/com.apps.myshop E/StorageException: The server has terminated the upload session java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
I use next rules

```
 rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

There are examples of my log errors

```
StorageException has occurred.
    User is not authenticated, please authenticate using Firebase Authentication and try again.
     Code: -13020 HttpResult: 401
2022-04-28 17:26:45.646 30490-30886/com.apps.myshop E/StorageException: The server has terminated the upload session
    java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.serverStateValid(UploadTask.java:339)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.shouldContinue(UploadTask.java:308)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:229)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7$com-google-firebase-storage-StorageTask(StorageTask.java:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 401,    "message": "Firebase App Check token is invalid."  }}
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:445)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:462)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:453)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:289)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:76)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:68)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(UploadTask.java:477)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(UploadTask.java:276)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:224)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7$com-google-firebase-storage-StorageTask(StorageTask.java:1072) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:2) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
2022-04-28 17:26:45.646 30490-30886/com.apps.myshop E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    User is not authenticated, please authenticate using Firebase Authentication and try again.
     Code: -13020 HttpResult: 401
2022-04-28 17:26:45.647 30490-30886/com.apps.myshop E/StorageException: The server has terminated the upload session
    java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.serverStateValid(UploadTask.java:339)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.shouldContinue(UploadTask.java:308)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:229)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7$com-google-firebase-storage-StorageTask(StorageTask.java:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 401,    "message": "Firebase App Check token is invalid."  }}
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:445)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:462)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:453)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:289)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:76)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:68)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(UploadTask.java:477)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(UploadTask.java:276)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:224)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7$com-google-firebase-storage-StorageTask(StorageTask.java:1072) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:2) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
2022-04-28 17:26:45.655 30490-30490/com.apps.myshop E/Error while uploading: Error while uploading image to db
    com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: User is not authenticated, please authenticate using Firebase Authentication and try again.
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.snapStateImpl(UploadTask.java:524)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.snapStateImpl(UploadTask.java:50)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.snapState(StorageTask.java:343)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.TaskListenerImpl.onInternalStateChanged(TaskListenerImpl.java:85)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.tryChangeState(StorageTask.java:390)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.tryChangeState(StorageTask.java:426)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.serverStateValid(UploadTask.java:342)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.shouldContinue(UploadTask.java:308)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:229)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7$com-google-firebase-storage-StorageTask(StorageTask.java:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.serverStateValid(UploadTask.java:339)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.shouldContinue(UploadTask.java:308) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:229) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7$com-google-firebase-storage-StorageTask(StorageTask.java:1072) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:2) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 401,    "message": "Firebase App Check token is invalid."  }}
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:445)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:462)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:453)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:289)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:76)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:68)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(UploadTask.java:477)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(UploadTask.java:276)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:224)
```

Comment: The error is very clear. Are you sure your user is authenticated before trying to access the storage?

Comment: Yes, the upload image activity is not launched before signing in

Answer (score 1):

Try adding create, although I suspect create should be included with write.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write, update, delete, create;
    }
  }
}
```